# Prove that $(A \cap B)^\perp ⊃ A^\perp + B^\perp$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, transpose

Let $A$ and $B$ be subspaces of a vector space V (not necessarily
finite-dimensional). For any $C \subset V$, $C^\perp \subset V^∗$ is its annihilator.

**1.** Prove that $(A \cap B)^\perp ⊃ A^\perp + B^\perp.$

**2.** Prove that $(A\cap B)^\perp = A^\perp + B^\perp$ if it is given that the following three lemmas
are true:

**L1.** $\dim(A + B) = \dim(A) + \dim(B) – \dim(A \cap B)$

**L2.** $(A + B)^\perp = A^\perp \cap B^\perp$

**L3.** $\dim(A^\perp) = \dim(V) – \dim(A)$ for any subspace $A$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: sorry, i do not know how to do it. I confused with transpose or inverse power. i don't know ⊥ this symbol exits

Answer (score 1):

For 1. start with $f \in A^{\perp}$ and $g \in B^{\perp}$.
Then $f(a) = 0$ and $g(b) = 0$ for all $a \in A$ and $b \in B$ by definition of $^\perp$.
We now want to show that $f + g \in (A \cap B)^{\perp}$, that is $(f + g)(c) = 0$ for all $c \in A \cap B$.

If $c \in A \cap B$, then $c \in A$ and $c \in B$.
Can you show that $(f + g)(c) = 0$?

The other statements are similar to prove.